# How to penalize a tensorflow dnn regressor model based on specific conditions?

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, regression, optimization

I want to modify the cost function such that the model is **penalized more** if it gives bad predictions for certain important entities (say top selling products in case of demand prediction). Is it possible?

Comment: You can do that by adding a term with a suitably weighted indicator function for important entities to your cost function. However, to get a more specific answer, I suggest presenting what you are doing now (code snippet) and what you have tried to solve it already.